# Vigenere cipher decoding not working properly

Tags: c, c-strings, vigenere

I am writing a vigenere cipher to be used as part of a loadable kernel module. Thus, I cannot use the string library. This is why I have included separate loops to get the key and input lengths as well. The include statement and the main are only included for testing.

Whenever I use a key that is not all caps, the program will crash due to an address sanitizer error. This only happens when I include the code that is supposed to convert the key input to uppercase. I am unsure of where this is incorrect, as my method to convert to uppercase is the same as I have seen on stack overflow in the past. It will run fine and not crash without those lines.

In addition, the decoding phase is not working as expected, it is giving the incorrect decoded message. The only possible problem that I can imagine is where I allow the input to contain spaces, but I do not think that is the issue since I am simply adding a space to the string. I would really appreciate some input as to where I am going wrong in this code. 
The complete error when attempting to convert to uppercase is:

```
==25694==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: BUS on unknown address 0x00010c98ae80 (pc 0x00010c989ac2 bp 0x7ffee3277610 sp 0x7ffee3277440 T0)
    #0 0x10c989ac1 in encrypt (vig:x86_64+0x100001ac1)
    #1 0x10c98aca1 in main (vig:x86_64+0x100002ca1)
    #2 0x7fff5c419ef8 in start (libdyld.dylib:x86_64+0x16ef8)

==25694==Register values:
rax = 0x000000010c98ae80  rbx = 0x00007ffee3277440  rcx = 0x000000010c98ae4b  rdx = 0x0000000000000004  
rdi = 0x000000010c98ae80  rsi = 0x000000010c98ae4b  rbp = 0x00007ffee3277610  rsp = 0x00007ffee3277440  
 r8 = 0x00001000219315d0   r9 = 0x0000000000000004  r10 = 0x0000000000000000  r11 = 0x0000000000000000  
r12 = 0x0000000000000000  r13 = 0x0000000000000000  r14 = 0x0000000000000000  r15 = 0x0000000000000000  
AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: BUS (vig:x86_64+0x100001ac1) in encrypt
==25694==ABORTING
Abort trap: 6
```

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
char* encrypt(char* input, char* key)
{
    int keyLength = 0;
    int inputLength = 0;
    int i;
    int j;
    for(i = 0; key[i] != '\0'; i++) //Get the length of the key
    {
        keyLength++;
    }
    for(i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++) //Get the length of the input
    {
        inputLength++;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < keyLength; i++)
    {
        if(key[i] >= 'a' && key[i] <= 'z')
        {
             key[i] = key[i] - 'a' + 'A';
        }
    }

    char* encryptedMessage = (char *)malloc((inputLength+1)*sizeof(char)); //Malloc for the encrypted message
    char fixedKey[inputLength + 1];
    if(inputLength < keyLength)
    {
        for(i =0; i < inputLength; i++)
        {
            fixedKey[i] = key[i];
        }
    }
    for(i = 0, j = 0; i < inputLength; ++i, ++j) //If the key length is shorter than message length, loop the key to correct length
    {
        printf("Entered Loop\n");
        if(j == keyLength)
            j = 0;
        fixedKey[i] = key[j];
    }
    fixedKey[i] = '\0';
    for(i = 0; i < inputLength; ++i) //Encryption
    {
        if(input[i] == ' ')
        {
            encryptedMessage[i] = ' ';
            continue;
        }
        encryptedMessage[i] = ((input[i] + fixedKey[i]) % 26) + 'A';
    }
    encryptedMessage[i] = '\0';
    return encryptedMessage;
}
char* decrypt(char* input, char* key)
{
    int keyLength = 0;
    int inputLength = 0;
    int i;
    int j;
    for(i = 0; key[i] != '\0'; i++) //Get the length of the key
    {
        keyLength++;
    }
    for(i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++) //Get the length of the input
    {
        inputLength++;
    }
    for (i = 0; i <keyLength; i++)
    {
        if(key[i] >= 'a' && key[i] <= 'z')
        {
            key[i] = key[i] - 'a' + 'A';
        }
    }
    char* decryptedMessage = (char *)malloc((inputLength+1)*sizeof(char));
    char fixedKey[inputLength + 1];
    if(inputLength < keyLength)
    {
        for(i =0; i < inputLength; i++)
        {
            fixedKey[i] = key[i];
        }
    }
    for(i = 0, j = 0; i < inputLength; ++i, ++j) //Fix the key length if needed
    {
        if(j == keyLength)
            j = 0;
        fixedKey[i] = key[j];
    }
    fixedKey[i] = '\0';
    for(i = 0; i < inputLength; ++i) //Decryption
    {
        if(input[i] == ' ')
        {
            decryptedMessage[i] = ' ';
            continue;
        }
        decryptedMessage[i] = (((input[i] - fixedKey[i]) + 26) % 26) + 'A';
    }
    decryptedMessage[i] = '\0';
    return decryptedMessage;
}
int main()
{
    char* encrypted = encrypt("The quick brown fox jumps over lazy dogs","key");
    char* decrypted = decrypt(encrypted,"key");
    printf("Encrypted string is: %s\nDecrypted String is: %s\n",encrypted,decrypted);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the error tell you the source file and line number?  Post the complete error.

Comment: @stark I updated the post to include the full error

Comment: I don't think you can use `malloc` in a kernel module.

Comment: You are trying to convert a read-only string to upper case.

Comment: @dbush You are correct about that, I was going to fix that issue once I had the encryption and decryption working properly.

Comment: `"key""` is string literal and is immutable. from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal): `Attempting to modify a string literal results in undefined behavior`. `key[i] = key[i] - 'a' + 'A';` is undefined behavioud. Also, ever heard of `strlen` ? Use compund literal to make non-immutable.

Comment: The decryption error is because you don't convert upper and lower-case letters of the input string in the same way. If your input is all uppercase, the decryption works. In my opinion, your code has too many special cases. For example, you don't have to distinguish the cases where the key is shorter than the input; that is caught automatically. It's also not clear what happens when you convert characters that aren't letters or spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to modify a string literal.

You call `encrypted` as:

```
encrypt("The quick brown fox jumps over lazy dogs","key");
```

Then in `encrypt`, you modify the second parameter:

```
key[i] = key[i] - 'a' + 'A';
```

String literals are read-only, and attempting to modify them invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Make a local copy of `key` and modify that when performing the upper/lower case conversion.

Comment: I am assuming that doing char* keyCopy = key; would not work, since that would just create a pointer to key, which is still a string literal?

Comment: @ColinNull Correct.  You need to either make a copy of `key`, or perform the upper/lower case conversion when you create `fixedKey`.

Comment: Are char* themselves unable to be modified? For example, could I create another char* keyCopy, and then copy from key character by character, and then modify keyCopy? I fixed the issue with the key's case, but now I am having the same problem with the input's case (It needs to be made all capital or all lowercase), and I want to avoid modifying the return type of encrypt and decrypt if possible.

Comment: @ColinNull Depends on what it points to.  If it points to a string literal, then you can't modify what it points to.  If it points to an element of a `char` array or to malloc'ed memory, then you can.

Comment: So, the following would be invalid then? `char* inputCpy = NULL;
    for(i = 0; inputA[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        inputCpy[i] = input[i];
        if(inputCpy[i] >= 'a' && inputCpy[i] <= 'z')
        {
            inputCpy[i] = inputCpy[i] - 'a' + 'A';
        }
    }
    inputCpy[i] = '\0';`

Comment: @ColinNull It's invalid because `inputCpy` is a NULL pointer.  It has to point somewhere.  You're already using `malloc` and local arrays, so just use one of those methods.